# Update existing Mongo document with a field from another class

Tags: java, mongodb, morphia

I have two objects - object A and object B.

Object A is saved to the database and Object B is saved later on. I would like to update Object A using the `_id` field with a field from Object B. When I go to save the Object B into Object A, an entirely new document is produced.

Is there any annotations that I need to set inside of Object B that would allow it to be an entity of Object A, even if Object A class does not reference it in anyway.

Here is my update operation for Object B:

```
Query<ObjectB> query = datastore.createQuery(ObjectB.class).field("_id").equal(objectAId);
UpdateOperations<ObjectB> op = datastore.createUpdateOperations(ObjectB.class).set("newFieledForObjectA", objectBObject);

datastore.update(query, op);
```

Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: It's not really clear in the question, but you seem to talking about the difference between embedding the content within Object A instead of referencing into a new collection of Object B entries. There are of course different annotations, but it really depends on what you want to do. More than likely you have something presently like `DBRef`, which is a really bad idea since whilst not "officially" deprecated, no new feature added to MongoDB releases for over 6 years actually supports this anymore. And things around it are actively being removed. Would be clearer with classes and documents

Comment: @NeilLunn Thank you for that insight. In regards to your `DBRef` comment, what are the alternatives? Right now I am using Morphia to manage object references in MongoDB and I am pretty sure that is `DBRef` if I am not mistaken.